# Setting SciChartSurface background to transparent makes it black Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, scichart

In Xamarin.Android if you set the background to transparent it just makes the background black. 
Code:

```
this.sciChartSurface.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
this.sciChartSurface.Background.Alpha = 0;
this.sciChartSurface.Background.SetAlpha(0);
```

Comment: Hope [this](https://www.scichart.com/questions/question/chart-background-always-black) may help.

Comment: Have you checked if the top container allows Transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the default RenderSurface implementation in Scichart Android uses OpenGL, which does not allow transparency or compositing of views under the chart.

However, SciChart provides an alternative which allows you to do this.

Have a look at https://www.scichart.com/questions/question/transparent-bacground and set the RenderSurface on the SciChartSurface to a [GLTextureView](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/SciChart.Drawing~com.scichart.drawing.opengl.GLTextureView.html) instance and it should work

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Xamarin.IOS? GLTextureView doesnt seem to exist.

Comment: For SciChart iOS set SCIChartSurface.isOpaque = false and set background color transparent https://www.scichart.com/questions/question/transparent-graph-background-and-animation-techniques